# Depth first search bug?

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

So I have a matrix of N×M. At a given position I have a value which represents a color. If there is nothing at that point the value is `-1`. What I need to do is after I add a new point, to check all his neighbours with the same color value and if there are more than 2, set them all to `-1`.

If what I said doesn't make sense what I'm trying to do is an algorithm which I use to destroy all the same color bubbles from my screen, where the bubbles are memorized in a matrix where `-1` means no bubble and `{0,1,2,...}` represent that there is a bubble with a specific color.

Also, if you have any suggestions I'd be grateful. Thanks.
This is what I tried and failed:

```
public class Testing {

    static private int[][] gameMatrix=
        {{3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
        {1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0},
        {2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0},
        {0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        };

    static int Rows=6;
    static int Cols=10;
    static int count;
    static boolean[][] visited=new boolean[15][15];
    static int NOCOLOR = -1;
    static int color = 1;

    public static void dfs(int r, int c, int color, boolean set)
    {
        for(int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr++) 
            for(int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc++)
                if(!(dr == 0 && dc == 0) && ok(r+dr, c+dc))
                {
                    int nr = r+dr;
                    int nc = c+dc;

                    // if it is the same color and we haven't visited this location before
                    if(gameMatrix[nr][nc] == color && !visited[nr][nc]) 
                    {
                        visited[nr][nc] = true;
                        count++;

                        dfs(nr, nc, color, set);

                        if(set)
                        {
                            gameMatrix[nr][nc] = NOCOLOR;
                        }
                    }
                }
    }

    static boolean ok(int r, int c)
    {
        return r >= 0 && r < Rows && c >= 0 && c < Cols;
    }

    static void showMatrix(){
        for(int i = 0; i < gameMatrix.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int j = 0; j < gameMatrix[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + gameMatrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ]");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    static void putValue(int value,int row,int col){
        gameMatrix[row][col]=value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Initial Matrix:"); 
        putValue(1, 4, 1);
        putValue(1, 5, 1);
        putValue(1, 4, 2);
        showMatrix();

        for(int n = 0; n < Rows; n++)
            for(int m = 0; m < Cols; m++)
                visited[n][m] = false;

        //reset count
        count = 0;
        dfs(5,1,color,false);
        //if there are more than 2 set the color to NOCOLOR
        for(int n = 0; n < Rows; n++)
            for(int m = 0; m < Cols; m++)
                visited[n][m] = false;
        if(count > 2)
        {
            dfs(5,1,color,true);
        }
        System.out.println("Matrix after dfs:");
        showMatrix();
    }

}
```

Comment: (have added [tag:java] to get syntax highlighting and attract more people; if this is wrong please just edit)

Comment: ok 10x :D -and other chars so I can actually post the comment-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue you are encountering is that you do not check the upper row and leftest col:

```
static boolean ok(int r, int c)
{
    return r > 0 && r < Rows && c > 0 && c < Cols;
}
```

you should check for `r >= 0`, `c>= 0`

Second issue is you are using `dfs()` twice, but the **`visited` field is static - it is all set to `true` before the second run of `dfs()`** you need to initialize it back to `false` in all fields before the second run, or the algorithm will terminate instantly without doing anything [since all the nodes are already in `visited` - and the algorithm will decide not to re-explore these nodes.].

Comment: @Fofole: Look at the second issue as well.

Comment: And that concludes it:D This fixes my problem I think. Thanks.

Comment: @Fofole: Then it is probably an additional issue. Try stepping with a debugger and find out when it happens and why. If you still fail to find it - post the new code [after the latest modifications] and a sample input where the algorithm fails [input, expected output and actual output].

Comment: Thanks a lot for everything. I actually found the problem. You've been of great help wish I could give you more than +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code counts diagonal cells as neighbours too. If you want only left/right/top/bottom cells than you can check

```
if(!(dr == 0 && dc == 0) && ok(r+dr, c+dc) && dr * dc == 0)
```

You also need to count first cell. You don't count cell you start from.

Comment: @Fofole It seems you don't count first cell you start from

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after a [flood-fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) (perhaps with the slightly odd constraint that there must be at least two neighbours of the same colour)?  I'm not sure why depth-first-search is appropriate here.